# Estou criando um quiz e não consigo fazer a verificação com javascript

Tags: javascript

O que eu estou tentando fazer é selecionar a alternativa e ao verificar mostre com o alert se a resposta esta certa ou errada. A cada resposta correta vai somando os acertos e se errou vai somando erros.
 Mas ao verificar a resposta não mostra o alert é enviado para a url.

```js
      var acertos=0;
var erros=0;

function verificar(){
  var form =document.getElementByName('form');
  var correctanswer =document.getElementByName("B");
form.addEventListener('onclick', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (correctanswer.checked) {
       acertos== acertos++;
        alert("Resposta Correta!"+ acertos);
    }else{
        
       alert("Resposta Errada!" + erros );
    }


});
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-10">
                    <h2>ALFABETO</h2> 

                         <video controls="true" width="500" height="300" id="01" src="video/video1.mp4"></video>
                            <form name ="form">
                                <p>Selecione a opção que corresponde a letra sinalizada</p>
                                <label>
                                    <input type="radio" name="resposta1" value="A"/> Letra A</label>
                                <label>
                                    <input type="radio" name="resposta1" value="B"/> Letra B</label><br>
                                <label>
                                    <input type="radio" name="resposta1" value="C"/> Letra C</label>
                                <label>
                                    <input type="radio" name="resposta1" value="D"/> Letra D</label><br>
                                <button onclick="verificar()">verificar</button>


                    </form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Bom pelo que entendi, você precisa emitir um alerta e somar um acerto caso a resposta esteja certa, eu fiz umas alterações no seu html e refiz o script

```js
function verificar(){
      var resposta = document.getElementById("ib");
      var erros = 0;
      var acertos = 0;
      if(resposta.checked){
        acertos++;
        alert("ACERTOU - Numero de acertos: " + acertos);
      }
      else{
        erros++;
        alert("ERRADO - Numero de erros: " + erros);
      }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <title>repl.it</title>
        <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
      </head>
      <body>
        <script src="index.js"></script>
        <div class="col-md-10">
          <h2>ALFABETO</h2> 
            <video controls="true" width="500" height="300" id="01" src="video/video1.mp4"></video>
            <p>Selecione a opção que corresponde a letra sinalizada</p>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="resposta1" value="A"/> Letra A</label>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="resposta1" id="ib" value="B"/> Letra B</label><br>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="resposta1" value="C"/> Letra C</label>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="resposta1" value="D"/> Letra D</label><br>
            <button onclick="verificar()">verificar</button>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Nesta condição ele checa se o elemento com id **ib** foi selecinado

```
if(resposta.checked){}
```

Comment: Obrigado Richard Santos consegui emitir o alert mas não consigo mostrar o número de acertos e o número de erros.

Comment: Pronto, desculpa só pude responder hoje.